# Problems with nodejs in linux when running a command npm install nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When running...

```
npm install nodejs
```

...I get the following error:

> npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
>   npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.14

I'm using:

- `npm` 3.10.3
- `node` 6.5.0
- `ubuntu` 14.04 LTS
- `Linux kernel` 3.18.3-031803-generic

Comment: If npm is installed then node should also be installed.  Not sure what a nodejs npm package would do.

Comment: Formatting, moved error description to the top for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Those are warnings, not errors. Typically a warning is not fatal and installation completes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. It is a warning that fseventsd, which is Mac OS specific, it can't be installed on Linux.

It's `open bug` here you can review it:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11632